# Problemas con el $_GET

Tags: php, json, http

Tengo este código y un valor en el url que llamo con la función: $_GET (llamado cID=(Numero)) estoy trancado y no puedo hacer que se cumpla la consulta que hago con el json, la única forma que funciona es agregando el numero manualmente, pero necesito que lo tome del navegador.

en esta consulta:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM calendar where customers_id = '11'");
```

el numero 11 debe ser tomado del url con la funcion $_GET he colocado el siguiente código y la tabla desaparece, no lee la url y me devuelve un valor de cero:

He probado con:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM calendar where customers_id = '$_GET['cID']'");
```

y con:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM calendar where customers_id = '.$_GET['cID'].'");
```

y con:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM calendar where customers_id = '.$HTTP_GET_VARS['cID'].'");
```

y no funciona

esta es la URL original la variable es &cID=(Valor) y el valor de &cID=(Valor) es el que necesito para general el Query:

http://localhost/manager/adminx1/calendario_customers.php?page=1&cID=11&action=edit

aquí les dejo el código completo pero no funciona, podrían ayudarme con esto:

```
if($type == 'fetch')
{
  $action = (isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '');
  $events = array();

  $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM calendar where customers_id = '$_GET['cID']'");

  while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  {
    $e = array();
    $e['id'] = $fetch['id'];
    $e['title'] = $fetch['title'];
    $e['start'] = $fetch['startdate'];
    $e['end'] = $fetch['enddate'];
    $e['customers_id'] = $_GET['cID'];


    array_push($events, $e);
  }
  echo json_encode($events);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero de todo, si algo no te funciona, verifica antes de hacer cambios si te lanza algún tipo de resultado las variables que esperas que lo tengan, y si lo lanza, que resultado es.

```
var_dump($_GET['cID']);
```

Debería darte una salida en el navegador similar a esto:

```
string '11' (length=1)
```

Como podrás comprobar, a pesar de ser un número lo representa como un string.

Si quieres convertirlo a integer, basta con poner delante de la variable `(int)`.

```
var_dump((int)$_GET['cID']);
```

En este caso daría una salida en el navegador como esta:

```
int 1
```

Si todo va bien y recibimos los datos correctamente es hora de pasar los parámetros a la consulta.

Al estar utilizando las dobles comillas `"` para la consulta, no es necesario andar escapando ni entrecomillando la variable. Puedes pasarle directamente una variable.

Ya que lo que esperas en un número como identificador, la consulta la admitirá siendo un `string` o un `integer`. Pero como buena práctica, si esperas un número entero, lo ideal sería pasarle un número entero a la consulta.

```
// he puesto 0 como alternativa pero puedes poner lo que necesites
$id = (isset($_GET['cID'])) ? (int)$_GET['cID'] : 0;
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM calendar where customers_id = $id");
```

Si probando con un valor estático te da resultados, está claro que no es problema de consulta a primera vista. Con los `var_dump()` anteriores podrás comprobar si te llegan los parámetros desde la url, y que parámetros son los que recibes realmente.

---

**Añado**

Sobre el código que has puesto después, revisa esta línea:

```
$strSQL = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM calendar where customers_id =" . $_GET['cID'];
```

Le falta cerrar la función `mysqli_query`.

```
$strSQL = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM calendar where customers_id =" . $_GET['cID']);
```

---

**EDITADO 2º**

Puedes probar a ver todos los parámetros añadidos que trae la url:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Con la url del comentario, debería darte una salida así:

```
array (size=3)
  'page' => string '1' (length=1)
  'cID' => string '11' (length=2)
  'action' => string 'edit' (length=4)
```

Comment: agradecido, he colocado tu recomendacion y el valor me da cero, me muestra los cID que contienen el valor de cero esta perfecto  ahora como hago para que me lea el valor del (int)$_GET['cID'] en vez de cero???? este es el valor que tengo en el link: http://localhost/manager/adminx1/calendario_customers.php?page=1&cID=11&action=edit en este caso quiero que solo me muestre los que sean valor 11 por que la barra del get asi lo tiene,

Comment: Justamente Oscar el $id = (isset($_GET['cID'])) ? (int)$_GET['cID'] : 11; el numero 11 que esta escrito a mano desearia que fuera el del (int)$_GET['cID'] lo he colocado y se desaparece la consulta, deja en blanco la pantalla

Comment: Prueba con la última edición que he puesto. Es extraño que GET no te recoja correctamente los datos de la url. ¿Puede estar sobreescribiendo en alguna parte del script antes de llegar ahí?

Comment: Pero en el script que has puesto, la variable $_GET aparece en varias ocasiones. Si es la que trae el valor, y no te llega correctamente, tendrás que ir al script que lo recoge y valorarlo allí. Y desde ese script, ver por que no te lo envía correctamente.

Answer (score 2):

prueba esto

```
$strSQL="SELECT * FROM calendar where customers_id =".$_GET['cID'];
 $query = mysqli_query($con,$strSQL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo lo expuesto en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5884896/1468942) del SO en inglés:

`$_GET` no es una función sino un array por lo que para acceder:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['cID']; //Sustituye por el QueryString deseado.
```

Answer (score 1):

No estás escapando los caracteres en tu query.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM calendar where customers_id = '".$_GET['cID']."'");
```

Comment: Las variables numéricas no necesitan ser escapadas. Las comillas en este caso no son necesarias.

Comment: Osea, que en PHP hacer: = `'$_GET['cID']'` ¿es válido? ¿Usar apóstrofes dentro de apóstrofes es correcto?

Comment: Creo que no entendí bien tu respuesta. Mira la respuesta de @JorgeMarquez.

Comment: Ah vale, te refieres a los apóstrofes fuera de $_GET. Sí tienes razón, incluso creo se podría haber hecho así: `" ... $_GET['cID']"` por la interpolación de strings xD. Damn it, hace mucho no toco PHP.